# Navbar multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm fiddling around with this design I found on http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu but I'm having a bit of an issue when the navbar is scaled down in the browser. So full width of the browser it looks like img 1 below....and when scaled down it turns into a hamburger menu with a dropdown as depicted in img 2. The problem is it repeats since I added an extra li tag to add in 'Super Awesome Menu'. So, my question is how to remove that extra repetition in img 2(it should retain in in full width like img 1).

I tried some of the simple removeclasses but they did not work. I'm sure it's super simple and I'm just failing to see it.

[image]
[image]

I stuck the code up here (since for whatever reason it's a huge pain to indent jquery on here)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxZLKo

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>     
            <div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href='#' class="current">Super Awesome Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                    <li class='active'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Join</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--end cssmenu-->
        </nav> <!--end nav-->
    </header> <!--end header-->
</div> <!--end wrapper-->
```

Comment: are you trying to add a logo?

Comment: Let me try to clarify as I may be confusing. I want it to look like this http://imgur.com/a/y28wo     Super Awesome Menu should always show.

Comment: For clarity, that second picture shows when the browser width is resized down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using media queries. Put this line of code in you css and you are good to go.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 926px) { #cssmenu ul.open li:nth-child(1){ display:none !important; } }
```

It will hide the first child in this case super mega awesome if you do `li:nth-child(2)` it will hide Home etc.

Comment: YUP that fixed it. I feel bad that Raja said almost the same thing but yours works. Sorry Raja :(   Thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no extra link "Super Awesome Menu"

It's just the name of your menu as you configured it on lines 5 & 73 in Javascript Section of your code snippet. It's your `title` parameter

```
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   title: "Super Awesome Menu",  
   format: "multitoggle"  
});
```

Just let it empty or find another name !

Comment: That's true but if I remove that the navbar title becomes empty when it sizes down. I'm looking for this: http://imgur.com/KUe0DmL

Comment: You want that your first link is always shown that's it ?

Comment: If by that you mean 'Super Awesome Menu' then yes. As depicted here (second picture shows browser window width reduced to set off the hamburger-style) imgur.com/a/y28wo

Comment: Ok, the problem is how will you open the submenu if "title" menu is a link ?

Comment: Again, I think I may have just been unclear. The goal was to have a navbar with the title 'Super Awesome menu' and then actual navlinks. Then, when resized, the browser would use this new hamburger menu to give a dropdown of the navbar instead. The issue was that it just had a repeat since I added another link to it. Not a fault in the design, just I had to account for it since it loops through all the li tags to form the new menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

> @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {   #cssmenu ul.open
>   li:first-child{
>       display:none !important;   } }

Comment: Didn't work for me...but I'm not sure I put it in the correct place to be honest